# Should metrics be corrected by the weights of the model?

Tags: classification, cart, accuracy, confusion-matrix

The question is simple. If I have an unbalanced dataset, which I want to classify according to the the values of binary response, and I use weights in a model to balance it (let's say it is a decision tree), how should I calculate accuracy (or misclassification) of that model? For example, if I want to calculate accuracy, the equation should look like this:

```
     ACCURACY<- ((TRUE POSITIVE* WEIGHT_OF_CLASS_POSITIVE) + 
                (TRUE NEGATIVE * WEIGHT_OF_CLASS_NEGATIVE)/ SUM_OF_WEIGHTS
```

OR like this:

```
     ACCURACY<- (TRUE POSITIVE + TRUE NEGATIVE)/ NUMBER_OF_OBSERVATIONS
```